# Property of two classes

Tags: objective-c

I want to have a result that looks like this player.type.property, An example of this is with UILabel, self.label.text. The .text being the property of the two classes.

A suggestion I have had is to do something like this:

```
player.type = [[MyCustomObject alloc] init];
player.type.property = @"value";
```

Although I'm not quite sure exactly how to go about doing this correctly, every method I have tried doesn't work.

Here is what I have tried:

```
Marketplace.h
#import "Item.h"
@interface Marketplace : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) Item *market;

Item.h
@interface Item : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) int price;

Starter.m
#import "Marketplace.h"
#import "Item.h"
@implementation MainGameDisplay
{
    Marketplace *market;
    Item *itemName;
}

-(void) executedMethod {
    market.itemName = [[market alloc] init];
    //2 errors: "Property 'itemName not found on object of type 'MarketPlace'" and "No visible @interface for 'MarketPlace' declares the selector alloc"
    market.itemName.price = 5; //"Property 'itemName' not found on object of type 'Marketplace*'"
}
```

Comment: @VitalyS. I'm not sure how to define the property types and initialise it. And by MyCustomObject, which object is it referring to, player or type?

Comment: What exactly do you want? What methods have you tried? Please elaborate your question.

Comment: @VitalyS. I have edited my question to show what I have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each pointer to class object must be alloc init, so you need to over-write the -(id)init inside its class.

```
Item.h
@interface Item : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger price;


Marketplace.h
#import "Item.h"
@interface Marketplace : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) Item *item;//Item is a class, must use strong or retain
Marketplace.m
-(id)init{
if (self = [super init]) {
  self.item = [[Item alloc] init];//Item must alloc together when MarcketPlace init
}
return self;
}
```

*Then you just init the Marketplace

```
@implementation MainGameDisplay
{
    Marketplace *market;
    Item *itemName;
}

-(void) executedMethod {
    market = [Marketplace alloc] init];
//Now you can access
    market.item.price = 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 . make a Interface named PlayerType Put some property there and synthesize them.
2. now make a Interface named Player and import the PlayerType Interface there.
3. make a property of PlayerType Interface like @property(nonatomic, strong) PlayerType *type.

1. now made variable of Player it will allow you to access property of a property.

Comment: I have done this already but it still doesn't work. If you check my edit in the question, I'm sure you'll see the problem.